# Chi-Square minimization

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting

Suppose you have N correlated data points and M parameters to fit a model. Then, you can construct the $\chi^2$ function as

$\chi^2 = (\vec{y}_{data} - \vec{y}_{theo}) \cdot C^{-1} \cdot (\vec{y}_{data} - \vec{y}_{theo})$ ,

where $\vec{y}_{data}$ is the vector with the data points, $\vec{y}_{theo}$ is the theoretical vector with the M parameters that follows the model under test and $C^{-1}$ is the covariance matrix of data points. Thus, to best fit the model, you need to minimize $\chi^2$ with respect to the M parameters, i.e.,

$\frac{\partial \chi^2}{\partial a_i} = 0, \quad i=0,1,...,M-1$.

What is the best function on Mathematica to do this job? In addition, a correlation matrix must be a sub-product of this procedure. NonlinearModelFit didn't work in this situation, and I'm not finding any useful build-in function.

Thanks in advance,
Gabriel.

Comment: I am quite confident that it is`LinearModelFit` or `NonlinearModelFit` what should be employed here.  What happend when you tried `NonlinearModelFit`? What was the code? Why do you think it did not work? How the the model look? Many. many questions that are open...

Comment: You should use `NMinimize`

Comment: If you have real data and the model with parameters, please share to get quick response.

Comment: You didn't even mention if the model is linear or not.

Comment: The model isn't linear. I found an alternative to this type of analysis: one can minimize the function with **Nminimize** and then define a $\Delta \chi^2$ function such that

$\Delta \chi^2 = \chi^2 - \chi_{min}^2$, 

where $\chi_{min}^2$ is the value of the function in the minimum. Then, you can consult tables of confidence intervals to plot the regions of interest using the **ConditionalExpression** in the **Plot**. Anyway, thanks all for the time and the help. Hope this helps, too. 

Best regards,
Gabriel